# Can you help fix my package system?

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

for a while I have got a prohibition sign in my tool bar. When I click on it I get the message that "my installed packages have unmet dependencies".

My software updater tells me the following:

```
Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f
Transaction failed: The package system is broken
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:

linux-generic-hwe-16.04: Depends: linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 (= 4.15.0.58.79) but 4.15.0.58.79 is installed
                         Depends: linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04 (= 4.15.0.58.79) but 4.15.0.55.76 is installed"
```

I have been trying to install a new program (opencpn) but I need to fix the problem first.

Could someone help understand the problem?

Comment: Have you checked out this link?  Looks like your problem.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/904319/unmet-dependencies-linux-headers-linux-image?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, I ran sudo apt-get upgrade -f and the prohibition sign disappeared though it seems I still have some problems: at the end of the process log I get W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_ver8_7.bin for module i915
Processing triggers for dictionaries-common (1.26.3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-4.15.0-58-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Have you tried the other commands also or just that one

Comment: I have also tried sudo apt-get clean with no results, sudo apt-get autoclean with no results and sudo apt-get -f install with the following message: dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-4.15.0-58-generic (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-4.15.0-58-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Two links to read and try.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/934689/broken-kernel-packages-preventing-install-update,  and  https://askubuntu.com/questions/682564/e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1