# Error while installing MySQLServer

Tags: apt, server, dpkg, mysql, lock

First of all when I try to install mysql server with `sudo apt install mysql-server`, it is stuck generally at the stage %81 and waiting last lines like below

```
mysqld will log errors to /var/log/mysql/error.log
mysqld is running as pid 12759
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mysql.service → /lib/systemd/system/mysql.service.
```

After throw error at %81 or whatever, it gives me error

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Then when I want to remove all to do this I struggle and do many things after remove everything then try to install again, but had the same problems. I could not install yet.

---

```
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
mysqld will log errors to /var/log/mysql/error.log
mysqld is running as pid 61198
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mysql.service → /lib/systemd/system/mysql.service.

Progress: [ 94%] [##################################################################################################################################.........]
```

It's the log under `/var/log/mysql/error.log` (It's created when I try to install.):

```
2021-01-07T16:37:31.913172Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-01-07T16:37:33.162774Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-01-07T16:37:36.489807Z 6 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
2021-01-07T16:37:39.365949Z 6 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user boot. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3).
2021-01-07T16:37:44.690155Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) starting as process 84654
2021-01-07T16:37:44.706661Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-01-07T16:37:44.926828Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-01-07T16:37:45.027382Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011292] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Preparation of I/O interfaces failed, X Protocol won't be accessible'
2021-01-07T16:37:45.027520Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011300] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Setup of socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' failed, can't create lock file /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock.lock'
2021-01-07T16:37:45.231071Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-01-07T16:37:45.231641Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-01-07T16:37:45.238549Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/tmp' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2021-01-07T16:37:45.277687Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3'  socket: '/tmp/tmp.X9qpBhmSHc/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  (Ubuntu).
2021-01-07T16:37:45.312794Z 0 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user <via user signal>. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3).
2021-01-07T16:37:46.863139Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3)  (Ubuntu).
2021-01-07T16:37:47.950414Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) starting as process 84719
2021-01-07T16:37:47.957833Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-01-07T16:37:48.187217Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-01-07T16:37:48.275665Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011300] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Setup of socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' failed, can't create lock file /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock.lock'
2021-01-07T16:37:48.275861Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '127.0.0.1' port: 33060
2021-01-07T16:37:48.388116Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-01-07T16:37:48.388695Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-01-07T16:37:48.397497Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/tmp' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2021-01-07T16:37:48.444139Z 7 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user boot. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3).
2021-01-07T16:37:49.863113Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3)  (Ubuntu).
2021-01-07T16:37:51.181843Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) starting as process 84873
2021-01-07T16:37:51.194900Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-01-07T16:37:51.406520Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-01-07T16:37:51.504461Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-01-07T16:37:51.619732Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-01-07T16:37:51.620324Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-01-07T16:37:51.647930Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  (Ubuntu).
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682564/e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1)

Comment: no its not. At the beginning i was install mysql server correctly then i take this error. mean time i can install any package with apt just im struggling with mysql server

Comment: dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you trying to install MySQL on? Is it the desktop or server version? When the dependencies are being downloaded, are any of them *not* for `mysql-server-8.0`? They may have something like `5.7` on the end.

Comment: its for ubuntu 20.04, and server version 8.0. dependencies for mysql-server-8.0, i install mysql server with this https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/install-mysql-server-8-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-linux/

Answer (score 0):

If your system is low on memory it can result in the error you are experiencing during mysql installation. Check /var/log/syslog for out of memory error.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1195160)